# Dynamically creating properties during initialisation without knowing the number or names of the properties in advance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a class that should have a few groups of attributes that are interrelated with a very similar logic, but the number and name of such interrelated quantities is not known in advance.

Concretely, I have a few "time_durations" properties with their associated "number_of_samples" properties that are related via a "sampling_rate" attribute, and I want the "time_durations" and "number_of_samples" to be setable and getable.

For specific cases, I can code a property for each such pair of attribute, but in general I won't know then name or the number of such attribute in my class.

I'm essentially trying to assign a property during initialisation using something like `setattr(self, 'name', property(fget, fset))`, but when I try to access this property, it returns a property object instead of the result of the getter function.

Here's what I have so far.

```
class test(object): 
 def __init__(self, d, t_keys=['t'], sr_key='sampling_rate'): 
     self.__dict__ = d
      
     for k in t_keys: 
         k_duration = k+'_duration' 
         k_samples = k+'_samples' 

         def duration_get(self): 
             return self.__dict__[k_duration] 

         def duration_set(self, v):  
             self.__dict__[k_duration] = v 
             self.__dict__[k_samples] = int(round(self.__dict__[k_duration]*self.__dict__[sr_key])) 

         def samples_get(self): 
             return self.__dict__[k_samples] 

         def samples_set(self): 
             self.__dict__[k_samples] = v  
             self.__dict__[k_duration] = double(self.__dict__[k_samples])/self.__dict__[sr_key] 

         setattr(self, k_duration, property(duration_get, duration_set)) 
         setattr(self, k_samples, property(samples_get, samples_set))
```

And here's what I get in python

```
In [2]: a = dict(t_samples=10, s_samples=5, sampling_rate=1e9)                                                                 

In [3]: aa = test(a, ['t', 's'], 'sampling_rate')                                                                              

In [4]: aa.t_samples                                                                                                           
Out[4]: <property at 0x7f513a251b30>

In [5]: aa.t_duration                                                                                                          
Out[5]: <property at 0x7f513a251ea0>

In [6]: aa.__dict__                                                                                                            
Out[6]: 
{'t_samples': <property at 0x7f513a251b30>,
 's_samples': <property at 0x7f513a251220>,
 'sampling_rate': 1000000000.0,
 't_duration': <property at 0x7f513a251ea0>,
 's_duration': <property at 0x7f513a251bd0>}
```

I would like for `aa.t_samples` to return the call to the property getter instead of the property object itself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I may have answered my own question.

By overriding the `__setattr__` method, properties are not required.
I decided to use an attribute name convention in order not to pollute `self.__dict__` with underscored keys, but this is not strictly required.

```
class ObjDict(object):
    """ Object-like dict interface """
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__dict__ = d
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__dict__.__str__()
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__dict__.__repr__()
    def __getitem__(self, v):
        return getattr(self, v)
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        return setattr(self, k, v)
    def __len__(self):
        return self.__dict__.__len__()
    def _items(self):
        for i in self.__dict__.items():
            yield i
            

class SamplingParams(ObjDict):  
    """ ObjDict than automatically update related values using an attribute suffix convention """
    _sr_key = property(lambda self: 'sampling_rate')
    _duration = property(lambda self: '_duration')
    _samples = property(lambda self: '_samples')
    
    def __init__(self, d): 
        if not self._sr_key in d: 
            raise ValueError(f"Initialisation dict must contain a *{self._sr_key}* key") 
         
        super().__init__({**d}) 
             
        for k,v in d.items(): 
             setattr(self, k, v)  
              
    def __setattr__(self, k, v): 
        if k[-len(self._duration):] == self._duration: 
            self.__dict__[k] = v 
            self.__dict__[k.replace(self._duration, self._samples)] = int(round(v*getattr(self, self._sr_key))) 
        elif k[-len(self._samples):] == self._samples: 
             self.__dict__[k] = v  
             self.__dict__[k.replace(self._samples, self._duration)] = v/getattr(self, self._sr_key) 
        elif k == self._sr_key: 
            self.__dict__[self._sr_key] = v 
            for k in [i for i in self.__dict__.keys() if i[-len(self._duration):] == self._duration]: 
                setattr(self, k, getattr(self, k))
            for k in [i for i in self.__dict__.keys() if i[-len(self._samples):] == self._samples]: 
                setattr(self, k, getattr(self, k))  
        else: 
            super().__setattr__(k, v)
```

And here's the expected behaviour

```
In [2]: a = dict(t_samples=10, s_samples=5, sampling_rate=1e9)                                                                                          

In [3]: aa = SamplingParams(a)                                                                                                                          

In [4]: aa.t_duration                                                                                                                                   
Out[4]: 1e-08

In [5]: aa.sampling_rate = 10e9                                                                                                                         

In [6]: aa                                                                                                                                              
Out[6]: {'t_samples': 100, 's_samples': 50, 'sampling_rate': 10000000000.0, 't_duration': 1e-08, 's_duration': 5e-09}

In [7]: aa.s_samples = 500                                                                                                                              

In [8]: aa.s_duration                                                                                                                                   
Out[8]: 5e-08

In [9]: aa.sampling_rate = 1e9                                                                                                                         

In [10]: aa                                                                                                                                             
Out[10]: {'t_samples': 10, 's_samples': 50, 'sampling_rate': 1000000000.0, 't_duration': 1e-08, 's_duration': 5e-08}

In [11]: aa.v_samples = 20

In [12]: aa.v_duration
Out[12]: 2e-08
```

Any improvement, best practices, or cleanups are welcome.